# shift+enter/return for run does not work in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to python and programming in general but now I try to learn python-programming in spyder(Python 3.5).

I have a very simple question: to run a command and advance to the next line I should be able to simply click the button on top or use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, neither of these work. It does work in Jupyter but not in spyder.

Is there something wrong with my run settings?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible answers to your question.

1. If you don't have anything selected in the Spyder Editor and press <kbd>F9</kbd>, Spyder will evaluate the current line and automatically move to the next one.
2. If you want to run things in a similar way as in the Jupyter notebook, you can break a file in *cells*, by introducing comments of the form `# %%`. After that you'll see that the active cell is colored differently. Then you can evaluate those cells by running <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (to move to the next cell) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (to stay in the current one).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, changing the preferences for spyder solved the issue.
Below are some information with snapshots been taken.

1. Go to spyder preferences.
2. Select keyboard shortcuts.
3. Go to run selection.
4. Change the default one (in my case was F9 is the default).
5. Select your new shortcut (in my case I selected shift + Enter).
6. If this shortcut been used before in another default location a new window will be opened to alert you >> select Yes then Apply.
7. Done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work. It seems that the Ctrl + Return and Ctrl + Enter are not recognized by the editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this combination (`shift+enter`) firstly you have to divide to your code. And you can divide your code like this (`#%%`) and then you can use (`shift+enter`). Otherwise you can only use `f9`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and in keyboard shortcuts clicked 'restore to default' and after saving restarted Spyder and it worked for me again.